An auto-homeomorphism of a grid of balls maps the center to itself.
Suppose you have 9 closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$, stacked into a 3x3 grid, as displayed in the (not perfect) drawing.
s.t. the upper leftmost ball touches the North Pole of the ball below it precisely with its southpole.
Show that any auto-homeomorphism $f$ of $X$ maps the center ball (call it $Y$) to itself and has a fixed point.
My guess: $Y$ is the only one, which shares four points with its neighboring balls.
But I don't know what property of homeomorphisms ensures that this still must be the case after the mapping.
Additionally I believe a sphere can only get mapped to another sphere, e.g. not the hourglass figure induced by the top and bottom hemi-balls of two neighboring balls
(since the structure of the neighborhoods of the connecting point are not available on just one ball). Combined this would imply
that each ball can only be mapped to another ball, with the same number of shared points with its neighbors, which fixes the choice for $Y$.
I am not sure if this is even the right approach though, so I would appreciate any nod in the fastest direction.
The exercise question before it, requested the local homology groups of all points in $X$, for which I used a standard theorem, to show that this is the same as the reduced homology group of the sphere $S^{1}$ for all points inside of $X$ and 0 on the boundary, since $X$ is a manifold.
That $f$ has a fixed point would then to follow from Brouwer's fixed point theorem, since $f$ restricted to the boundary of $Y$ is like a  $S^2 \mapsto S^2$, as points on the boundary of $X$ can't be mapped to points inside of it (as it would change the local homology groups).


Lets introduce the following:

Definition: a point $x\in X$ is called local cut-point if for any open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, there is a connected open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V\subseteq U$ and $x$ is a cut-point of $V$.

One can easily prove that every homeomorphism maps local cut-points to local cut-points. And it is not hard to see that this particular $X$ has $12$ local cut-points: precisely the glueing points between those balls.
Next every homeomorphism $X\to X$ has to map interior into interior and boundary into boundary. This can be seen again by picking points and comparing small enough neighbourhoods. This time these are not cut-points, but removal of those points results in spaces with different homology.
This implies that every homeomomorphism $f:X\to X$ has to map ball into a ball. Because otherwise, we can find two points $x,y$ in the interior of one ball such that $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ lie in the interior of two different balls. Then I can connect them via path inside interior, and that path composed with $f$ has local cut-point in its image. Meaning a non local cut-point is mapped into local cut-point by $f$. Which is a contradiction.
This finally implies that middle ball has to be mapped into itself, because it is the only one with $4$ local cut-points. The rest follows from Brouwer's fixed point theorem for $f$ restricted to the middle ball.
